# Why do we ask the inclusion map to have full rank differential for a immersed submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

I just read the definition of an immersed submanifold in Lee's book. My understanding of it is like a manifold that lives inside an other manifold but which are topologically not necessarily compatible. But I don't understand why we ask in the definition that the differential of the inclusion map to be injective at each point (i.e. $(d\iota)_p$ injective)? What is the idea behind this? why is this interesting?

Comment: *In*jective, not surjective.

Comment: Full rank here means *injective* (as the dimension of the domain is *less* than the domain of the range). You want the image *locally* to be a submanifold.

Comment: right, injective, I corrected. @TedShifrin What do you mean by the image being locally a manifold?

Comment: Means that locally it is a k-plane in the ambient manifold due to rank theorem. You could try to read other reference where they using different definitions and see if that could answer your question.